# Shouldn't iPad2 have the "frosted blur" effect with iOS7?

Tags: ipad, ios

My iPad 2 looks like an iPhone 4, without 'frosted blur'. Is it correct for the iPad 2 to not have the blur/frost effect?

My iPhone 4S has it and some videos on YouTube purport to be iPad 2's and have it (not sure if release version of iOS7 in those videos). So is it correct that my iPad2 runs iOS7 without this effect? I cannot find any documentation to confirm they left this feature out on iPad 2 but in on 4S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to AnandTech (http://www.anandtech.com/show/7343/the-ios-7-review), the blur effect requires at least iPhone 4S or iPad 4.

> On the iPhone side, the iPhone 4 lacks the cool blur effect in a number of places (notification center and control center are the most obvious), and iPad 3 does as well.

Answer (score 0):

iPad 2 had this effect until iOS 7 Beta 5.